# Is it possible to Install Proxmox VE on top of Ubuntu 20 machine?

Tags: ubuntu, apt, ubuntu-20.04, proxmox

Is it possible to install Proxmox VE on on top of Ubuntu `ubuntu-20.04.2.0-desktop-amd64`?

[This article](https://www.linuxbabe.com/linux-server/install-proxmox-ve) is using Debian 10 buster but i would like to know if it is also possible on Ubuntu 20.04.

I already tried to run following steps:

```
echo "deb http://download.proxmox.com/debian/pve buster pve-no-subscription" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pve-install-repo.list

wget http://download.proxmox.com/debian/proxmox-ve-release-6.x.gpg -O /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/proxmox-ve-release-6.x.gpg
chmod +r /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/proxmox-ve-release-6.x.gpg
apt update
apt install proxmox-ve postfix open-iscsi
```

After that I am getting dependencies missing :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 proxmox-ve : Depends: pve-manager but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: pve-qemu-kvm but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: qemu-server but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: spiceterm but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: vncterm but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Installing Proxmox VE on Ubuntu is not supported.

Proxmox VE is [based on Debian](https://pve.proxmox.com/pve-docs/chapter-pve-installation.html) and relies on the packages that are available in the respective Debian version. Although not clearly visible in the error message, what you mentioned

> After that I am getting dependencies missing

is exactly what I would expect due to the different packages or rather package versions in Ubuntu and Debian.

The installation ISO of Proxmox VE includes a complete Debian system as well as the Proxmox VE packages (that you can get on download.proxmox.com). Therefore, you can install plain Debian (but not Ubuntu) on a system and install Proxmox VE on top of it. There is a [guide](https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Install_Proxmox_VE_on_Debian_11_Bullseye) on how to accomplish this on the public Proxmox VE wiki.

However, it is worth to note that the *kernel* that is shipped with Proxmox VE is Ubuntu-based. As it is more recent than the Debian kernel, this make newer hardware available.